# Pandas, when merging two dataframes and values for some columns don't carry over

Tags: python, pandas, merge, left-join, nan

I'm trying to combine two dataframes together in pandas using left merge on common columns, only when I do that the data that I merged doesn't carry over and instead gives NaN values. All of the columns are objects and match that way, so i'm not quite sure whats going on.

this is my first dateframe header, which is the output from a program

[image: df1]

this is my second data frame header. the second df is a 'key' document to match the first output with its correct id/tastant/etc and they share the same date/subject/procedure/etc
[image]

and this is my code thats trying to merge them on the common columns.

```
combined = first.merge(second, on=['trial', 'experiment','subject', 'date', 'procedure'], how='left')
```

with output (the id, ts and tastant columns should match correctly with the first dataframe but doesn't.

[image]

Comment: what are the `first.dtypes` and `second.dtypes`?

Comment: That's because you are using how='left', this will give entire data from the first dataset and the common columns from the second dataset. Instead use how="outer".

Comment: @PrakritiShaurya i tried the how='outer' method but it doesn't give me the desired format, instead it repeats the first dataset and expands it to more rows.

Comment: @noah both the first and second dtypes are objects

Answer (score 0):

Check your dtypes, make sure they match between the 2 dataframes. Pandas makes assumptions about data types when it imports, it could be assuming numbers are int in one dataframe and object in another.

For the string columns, check for additional whitespaces. They can appear in datasets and since you can't see them and Pandas can, it result in no match. You can use df['column'].str.strip().

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html